# How to create a Stack and a Queue?

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to create a stack and a queue for search algorithms (depth first/ breadth first/ best first) therefore I need to create a stack and a queue.

How can I create a Stack and a Queue in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use list as stack. A good documentation could be found over [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). Your code may look something like this

```
>>> stack = [3, 4, 5]
>>> stack.append(6)
>>> stack.append(7)
>>> stack
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> stack.pop()
7
>>> stack
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> stack.pop()
6
>>> stack.pop()
5
>>> stack
[3, 4]
```

You might want to `import queue` in your code for queue implementation

```
>>> import queue

>>> L = queue.Queue(maxsize=20)
>>> L.put(5)
>>> L.put(9)
>>> L.put(1)
>>> L.put(7)

>>> print(L.get())
5
>>> print(L.get())
9
>>> print(L.get())
1
>>> print(L.get())
7
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can use a deque object, which functions as both - check the docs for the functions it supports, and how to use it as a queue or stack.

```
from collections import deque
d = deque()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list as a stack with the following methods list.append(x) and list.pop(). As for a queue, you can use list.append(x) and list.list.remove().

For further reading, https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html